# EF Core 2.2 - StartsWith on two different columns

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a query to get all records where two different columns start with the same character:

```
var query = _db.Projects.AsQueryable();
query = query.Where(p => p.InternalOrder.StartsWith("G") || p.CostCenter.StartsWith("G"));
var list = query.toList();
```

This always ends in an exception. When I change the query so that only one column is queried everything works fine:

```
var query = _db.Projects.AsQueryable();
query = query.Where(p => p.InternalOrder.StartsWith("G") || p.InternalOrder.StartsWith("G"));
var list = query.toList();
```

Is this a bug or just not possible to do?

**EDIT:**
Here is the exception; tells me nothing:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at lambda_method(Closure , Project )
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIPartitionIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities[TOut,TIn](IEnumerable`1 results, QueryContext queryContext, IList`1 entityTrackingInfos, IList`1 entityAccessors)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at BMP_App.Controllers.Api.ProjectController.GetProjectList(DataSourceRequest request) in D:\...\Controllers\Api\ProjectController.cs:line 72
```

**EDIT2:**
This only happens when using in-memory database. No problem when using Sql-Server.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting? You tried to apply `StartsWith` to `CostCenter` column alone and was fine?

Comment: In order to provide help, you need to provide more details in your question, can you please show the exception message please?

Comment: @Neptune: see second query; yes, if only one column is involved it is fine

Comment: It's a `NullReferenceException` so one of the two string fields is null. It's better to check for null values on strings unless you guarantee them not to be null.
The reason it doesn't happen with SQLServer is that the statement is convreted into SQL statements and run in SQL Server which doesn't throw null exceptions but rather ignores null values.
Try to change the query to check for null values:
query.Where(p => (p.InternalOrder != null && p.InternalOrder.StartsWith("G)) || (p.CostCenter != null && p.CostCenter.StartsWith("G")))

Comment: @Neptune: thanks, that was the solution. I expected such a simple statement to behave the same on Sql-Server and in-memory database. Good to know when using in-memory db for unit tests!

Comment: No worries I will add it as an answer so people seeing this in future can see the answer easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the exception you are getting is a NullReferenceException so one of the two string fields is null. It's better to check for null values on strings unless you guarantee them not to be null. The reason it doesn't happen with SQLServer is that the statement is convreted into SQL statements and run in SQL Server which doesn't throw null exceptions but rather ignores null values. Try to change the query to check for null values:

```
query.Where(p => (p.InternalOrder != null && p.InternalOrder.StartsWith("G))
  || (p.CostCenter != null && p.CostCenter.StartsWith("G")))
```